# Why does my laptop freeze sometimes when i excute this process

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I am creating a dataset of food to train my model, i use glob module to read images in a directory and matplotlib to read each image data, however sometimes this makes my laptop freezes which make me force it to shut down!

the following code (sometimes) causes this

```
data_dir ="/home/moumenshobaky/tensorflow_files/virtualenv/archive/training/Egg/*"
train_x = []
train_x.clear()
for filename in glob.glob(data_dir):

    train_x.append(mpimg.imread(filename).tolist())

data_dir ="/home/moumenshobaky/tensorflow_files/virtualenv/archive/training/Meat/*"

for filename2 in glob.glob(data_dir):
    train_x.append(mpimg.imread(filename2).tolist())
```

and sometimes the line code causes the same thing also

```
train_x_float = pixel/255.0 for pixel in train_x
```

Comment: What does Task Manager tell you when the code runs? What spikes up?

Comment: How many and how big are these files? Overusing RAM can cause freezes.

Comment: @taylorswiftfan i can't even launch task manager :/

Comment: @BatWannaBe i kept reducing the amount of the files till they are now 144 files, each file from 40 to 60 kb

Comment: @moumenShobakey Try to reduce the image size before appending & use the batch wise loading of images which will help to overcome ram issue. For more simplicity, you can use ImageDataGenerator of Keras.

Comment: Yes, looks like i'll try the generator thing , Timbus although recommended it to me, thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list in which you store all the images on your drive.

Consider to use generators (as to prepare the data for your training), freezing is normal as you use a lot of RAM memory; otherwise just load a part of your dataset if you still want to make some analysis. Some small overhead is also done by transforming the numpy array (loaded image) always to a list, you eliminate the transformation.

You could use this snippet to check for memory usage:

```
from sys import getsizeof
size_of_list_in_bytes = getsizeof(train_x)
size_of_list_in_mb = size_of_list_in_bytes / 1000000 (6 zeros).
```

As for the generator usages, should you use TensorFlow or Keras, you could have a look at `Sequence`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence or `ImageDataGenerator`. It really depends of the task, I recommend the former as it has more flexibility. Last but not least, `tf.data.Dataset()` are becoming more and more widespread. Each of these provide built-in generators.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why doesn't this always happen, beside that i clear the train_x eachtime i load the data :/

Comment: It may be the case that the RAM memory fluctuates, sometimes allocating more memory for some background processes and when your code actually runs, it's pure luck.

Comment: okey looks like i'll try the generator, thanks alot

Comment: i am indeed using tf.data.Dataset() but sadly the shape of my data doesn't fit it, it gives me 'Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.' and i still need a generator to load the data from the driver, update: i have just checked the imagedatagenerator and it's cool it gives me a Dataset directly

Comment: That is another question, and usually as per S.O rules they demand other questions/posts. However, as I want to help you fast, I will answer here. The problem is that you have nested lists of different lengths. You could use tf.ragged.constant(data). https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor

Comment: oh, i am sorry for that, i'll just stop talking :D, i really appreciate your help thanks alot

Comment: No problem, it's not about talking, see my fast answers&willingness to help,we can talk continously, I am just suggesting to abide by the rules of S.O.